# Configuring Dropzone.js fails

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone for first. My goal is to have a file uploader like below:
[image: Example picked from dropzonejs.com]

Unfortunately, my output is:
[image: My output]

This is my html page:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUploadedFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "myDropzone", id = "myDropzone", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <div id="previews" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-message box__input">
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" style="font-size: 23px; position: relative; top: 4px;"></i> <span style="margin-left: 20px">Drop files  to attach or browse</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="previewFiles"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success m-t-5" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

and for configuring dropzone:

```
$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
paramName: "files",
clickable: '#previews',
previewsContainer: "#previewFiles",
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
addRemoveLinks: true,
thumbnail: function (file, dataUrl) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
        file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
        var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");

init: function () {
    var self = this;
    // config
    self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
    self.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
    //New file added
    self.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        console.log('new file added ', file);
        $('.dz-success-mark').hide();
        $('.dz-error-mark').hide();
    });
}});
```

How can i change my config to have a uploader like the Example picked from dropzonejs.com? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a css issue. How do you style it? Did you load default css `https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.css`?

Comment: Yes, i used the correct css file

Comment: You are showing as desired look dropzone default appearance, but the html you have is not dropzone's suggested html and instead you are using the `previewsContainer` and `clickable` options to modify the look. So I am not sure what you really want, if you want dropzone's default look you should use dropzone default html and options http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage. You also should check the console for errors, because as you have the javascript right now I am sure there are some errors showing.

Comment: If i use the `$('#myDropzone').dropzone();` simply, the output is not different. Additionally, the single error i see in the console is `No url is provided`, which i guess is not related to the appearance stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the user who run into similar problem, i post the solution.
The point is to use **dropzone** class for the form.

The correct form declaration is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUploadedFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="dropzone", @name = "myDropzone", id = "myDropzone", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // Whatever you nees
}
```